# Get first digit separated in R

Tags: r, digits

I have one column in which first digit can be number, letter or some special character like #. However, I should be able to separate first digit in all cases and save those digits as a new column. I have worked with stringr -package and written: newcolumn <- str_extract(data$column, "{1}")

That works perfectly with letters and numbers, but is unable to understand special characters. How I should change the code, so that also that kind of digits woul be taken into account ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `is unable to understand special characters.` when `stringr::str_extract(c("abc", "#DSE", "123abc", "*ase"), ".{1}")` works perfectly fine and returns `[1] "a" "#" "1" "*"`

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the str_sub() function.

```
 x <- c("Apple", "%Banana", ".Pear")
 str_sub(x, 1, 1)
```